# Why my VBA function returning #NAME! error

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have created a VBA function, but I am receiving the #NAME error. I can't figure out what's wrong please help.

```
Function FirstWord(rng As Range) As String
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In rng
    If InStr(1, cell, " ") > 0 Then
        FirstWord = Left(cell, InStr(1, cell, " ") - 1)
        Exit Function
    End If
Next

    
End Function
```

Comment: Where is the function stored?

Comment: You need to create it in a module.

Comment: Try using Split(cell, " ")(0) instead.  It's a lot simpler.

Comment: You actually don't even need a custom function for this, you may be learning though and if so, all good.  Otherwise, look at LAMBDA functions, depending on your version of Excel of course.

Comment: Why not just use SEARCH() and IFERROR()? Then when you found a cell, just use `LEFT()` to pull the info left of the first space? e.g. `=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)`

Comment: I feel like `BILLY` isn't a real name, nor is that an authentic photo. Just guessing.

Comment: @Billy, friendly suggestion, change your for each to `For Each cell In Intersect(rng, rng.Worksheet.UsedRange).Cells` that way lazy users (like me) can click on the entire column and it won't impact performance. You have an `exit function` which would hopefully defend against this, but just good practice.